# CSS: Stretch an inline element to fill available width

Tags: css

I have a page with text and some images floated to the right, which the text flows around.

I want to put a heading in the text which has an underline (actually it's a `border-bottom` which I think will be easier in this case?)... now, my problem is that I want the heading (`h3`) element (and therefore the underline/bottom border) to stretch nicely across until it (almost) hits the image.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Inigo/xroLvh5w/)

```css
h3 {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
img {
  float: right;
  margin-left:15px;
  display:block;
  width:40%;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="#" alt="This is my image">
  <h3>This is my title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque totam cumque accusantium repellendus, illum, libero reiciendis est, explicabo obcaecati asperiores suscipit eum? Perferendis ipsa odio maxime, ullam, iste vero! Quis!</p>          
</div>
```

Using the `h3` tag, it seems to almost work, except that it doesn't respect the `margin-left` on the image.

I would want the underline/border to stretch right across the page if the image isn't there, so I don't want to have to manually specify widths.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `<h3>` the property `overflow:hidden`. This can prevent your header extending past the floated element:

```css
h3 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    float: right;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:block;
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="#" alt="This is my image">
     <h3>This is my title</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque totam cumque accusantium repellendus, illum, libero reiciendis est, explicabo obcaecati asperiores suscipit eum? Perferendis ipsa odio maxime, ullam, iste vero! Quis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque totam cumque accusantium repellendus, illum, libero reiciendis est, explicabo obcaecati asperiores suscipit eum? Perferendis ipsa odio maxime, ullam, iste vero! Quis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque totam cumque accusantium repellendus, illum, libero reiciendis est, explicabo obcaecati asperiores suscipit eum? Perferendis ipsa odio maxime, ullam, iste vero! Quis!</p>
</div>
```

[**A relevant read**](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)

Comment: Ah, wow! Excellent, problem solved! Many thanks. (Will accept in a minute when I am able)